# convert rows after column

Tags: r

I have csv file which reads like this

```
1        5
2        3
3        2  
4        6 
5        3
6        7
7        2 
8        1
9        1
```

What I want to do is to this:

```
1       5      4       6     7      2
2       3      5       3     8      1
3       2      6       7     9      1
```

i.e after every third row, I want a different column of the values side by side. Any advise?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What programming language do you propose to use for this ?

Comment: My advise: write it, and it will works.

Comment: if you are using a language like java, write a while loop to collect all the data into an array. Then below the while loop have a for loop that places the next data points from the array into a row. Have an if statement in the for loop that makes a new row every time six is reached. counter mod 6

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply. Actually I am trying to use R to do this. I dont know much of Java or any other programming language as such.

Comment: OK - I've added an `r` tag for you now - you can save yourself and others both time and effort in the future by tagging your question appropriately - the programming language is probably the single most important tag on any question.

Comment: Sincere apologies! I will keep this in mind next time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a <- read.table(text = "1        5
 2        3
 3        2  
 4        6 
 5        3
 6        7
 7        2 
 8        1
 9        1")

(seq_len(nrow(a))-1) %/% 3
# [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2

split(a, (seq_len(nrow(a))-1) %/% 3)
# $`0`
  # V1 V2
# 1  1  5
# 2  2  3
# 3  3  2

# $`1`
  # V1 V2
# 4  4  6
# 5  5  3
# 6  6  7

# $`2`
  # V1 V2
# 7  7  2
# 8  8  1
# 9  9  1

do.call(cbind,split(a, (seq_len(nrow(a))-1) %/% 3))
#   0.V1 0.V2 1.V1 1.V2 2.V1 2.V2
# 1    1    5    4    6    7    2
# 2    2    3    5    3    8    1
# 3    3    2    6    7    9    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this with matrix indexing.  It's a bit strange, but I find it interesting so I will post it.

You want an index matrix, with indices as follows.  This gives the order of your data as a matrix (column-major order):

```
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1
1, 2
2, 2
3, 2
4, 1
```

...

```
8, 2
9, 2
```

This gives the pattern that you need to select the elements.   Here's one approach to building such a matrix.  Say that your data is in the object `dat`, a data frame or matrix:

```
m <- matrix(
        c(
           outer(rep(1:3, 2), seq(0,nrow(dat)-1,by=3), FUN='+'), 
           rep(rep(1:2, each=3), nrow(dat)/3)
        ),
        ncol=2
     )
```

The `outer` expression is the first column of the desired index matrix, and the `rep` expression is the second column.  Now just index `dat` with this index matrix, and build a result matrix with three rows:

```
matrix(dat[m], nrow=3)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    1    5    4    6    7    2
## [2,]    2    3    5    3    8    1
## [3,]    3    2    6    7    9    1
```